# How to correctly partion WD "Advanced Format" drive (4k sector size) with Disk Druid?

Tags: linux, centos, partition, advanced-format

Unaligned Advanced Format drives with sector size of 4k will have degraded performance.

How do I make Disk Druid to partition drives correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the partitioning problem very easy. I dropped Disk Druid and before installing OS booted in linux rescue mode. Then I started *parted* and switched to *unit s* mode to use sectors. Then I created partitions I need so that every partition starts on mod8 sector (divisible by 8). That's all.

Answer (score 0):

See [this recent IBM developerWorks article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-4kb-sector-disks/index.html) about the topic. I'm not sure if Disk Druid supports partitioning based on sectors, meaning that it will let you specify the start of a partition based on sector number, rather then CHS, or size. If it doesn't I recommend partitioning manually, with a different tool, according to the advice in the article.

Comment: Yea, I read it. The problem is that there is no info on how to do that by Disk Druid, which is the default partitioning tool in CentOS/RedHat installer. On the disk itself it's written, that only Windows needs jumper manipulation and other OSes are good as they are. But that seem not to be so.